# snmpget via paramiko fails

Tags: python-2.7, snmp, paramiko

When I use an snmpget command in bash it works and I get the output I want, however when I run it through python via Paramiko, it fails and nothing is returned.

I suspect it is pulling too much information back.

```
for x in L2Switches:
    ssh.stdin, ssh.stdout, ssh.stderr = ssh.exec_command("snmpget -v2c -c <SNMPPASS> " + x + " HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::ifName | grep Master")
    for line in ssh.stdout:
        print(line)
        if "Master Switch on the internal network" in line:
           print(x + ' is the master switch')
        else:
           pass
```

I've tried using snmpwalk however it returns everything and the 'grep' function does not seem to be used.

**stderr output**

Checking the stderr output I can see it is parsing the exec_command as two commands on the bash line

I've included a snippet, if you understand SNMP you'll see it's shown the 'help' for the snmp command then tried to run the second part of the exec command by itself, however it reports it's missing the object name

```
          Missing object name

          for levels 'p1' to 'p2'

          [FS] pri token:    log to file/syslog for level 'pri' and above

          [FS] p1-p2 token:  log to file/syslog for levels 'p1' to 'p2'

          -C APPOPTS        Set various application specific behaviours:

          f:  do not fix errors and retry the request

          bash: line 1: HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::ifName: command not found
```

Comment: Did you even try reading the `stderr`?

Comment: @Martin, the stderr output shows that the system is reading the exec_command as two commands, it's doing an snmpget without a MIB and then just parsing the MIB as a seperate command

Comment: So then you will have to show us exact command that you pass to `exec_command`. Also, what kind of server are you connecting to? Is that a regular Linux server?

Comment: @Martin, I've just added it now, just a regular server, the command works when entering it on the bash line when directly connected however Python or rather Paramiko seems to have an issue parsing the exec_command as one bash command

Comment: I do not see **the command** in your question.

Comment: Martin, it's clearly there ` ssh.stdin, ssh.stdout, ssh.stderr = ssh.exec_command("snmpget -v2c -c <SNMPPASS> " + x + " HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::ifName | grep Master")`

Comment: No it’s not, we do not know what `SNMPPASS` and `x` are. We need [mcve].

Comment: @Martin - SNMPPASS is a confidential SNMP password that I'm not authorised to give out over the Internet. If you look carefully, x is just a iterable item in a list.

Comment: Sure, but in both there can be some symbols that confuses shell. But your call, you want our help.